# Need help with the Test Class for following Case Object Batch Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage, schedulebatch

I am new to Salesforce coding and trying to write my first test class. I have tried all day but can not get any coverage for this batch class. Can anyone please help me with the test class for this batch.

```
global class CaseOwnerManagerUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful,Schedulable {
    global CaseOwnerManagerUpdate() 
    {
    }
    global Database.Querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        //Return all open cases owned by a user
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Case_Owner_Manager__c, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Status != 'Closed' AND Owner.Type = 'User'  AND RecordType.DeveloperName IN ('Suppport','Support_New')]);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Case> scope) {
        //Iterate through the cases and build a set of owner ids that we can use to query the user object
        Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Case c : scope) {
            userIds.add(c.OwnerId);
        }
        
        //Query the user records for each of these case owners
        Map<Id, User> caseowners = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, ManagerId FROM User WHERE Id IN :userIds]);
        
        //Create a list that will hold cases that need to be updated
        List<Case> casesforupdate = new List<Case>();
        
        //Iterate through the cases and check to see if a manager update is needed
        for (Case c : scope) {
            if (c.Case_Owner_Manager__c != caseowners.get(c.OwnerId).ManagerId) {
                c.Case_Owner_Manager__c = caseowners.get(c.OwnerId).ManagerId;
                casesforupdate.add(c);
            }
        }
        
        //If we have any cases that need to be updated, update them
        if (casesforupdate.size() > 0) {
            update casesforupdate;
        }
        
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {
        //send confirmation email notifications
         AsyncApexJob a = [Select Id, Status,ExtendedStatus,NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email    from AsyncApexJob where Id =:BC.getJobId()];
      
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('Match Merge Batch ' + a.Status);
        mail.setPlainTextBody('records processed ' + a.TotalJobItems +   'with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) 
    {
        database.executebatch(new CaseOwnerManagerUpdate());
    }
    
}
```

Here is the test class for above batch that I have written and currently it is throwing this error while running test: 'System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object'.

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)

public class CaseOwnerManagerUpdateTest {
    static testMethod void testCaseOwnerManager() {
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
        User u1 = new User(Alias = 'standt1', Email='standarduser1@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser43431212@testorg.com');      
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@43431313testorg.com', ManagerId = u1.id);
        System.runAs(u){  
        Case cs = new Case();
        //cs.Owner.Type = 'User';
        cs.Status = 'Working';
        cs.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Support'; //ERROR System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
        cs.Case_Owner_Manager__c = u.Id;
        insert cs;
           
        Case cs1 = new Case();
        //cs1.Owner.Type = 'User';
        cs1.Status = 'Open';
        cs1.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Support_New';
        cs1.Case_Owner_Manager__c = u.Id;
        insert cs1;
        
        Case case1 = [SELECT Id, Case_Owner_Manager__c, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Status != 'Closed' AND Owner.Type = 'User'  AND RecordType.DeveloperName IN ('Suppport','Support_New')];    
        
            test.startTest();
            CaseOwnerManagerUpdate obj = new CaseOwnerManagerUpdate ();
            DataBase.executeBatch(obj); 
            Case c = new Case();
            if(c.Case_Owner_Manager__c != u.ManagerId )
            c.Case_Owner_Manager__c = u.ManagerId;
           

            System.assertEquals(u1.id, c.Case_Owner_Manager__c);
            System.assertNotEquals(u.id, c.Case_Owner_Manager__c);
            test.stopTest();
        }       
     }
}
```

Comment: to start with - get rid of seeAlldata=true; the testmethod should mock everything; and you need to set/mock `recordtypeId` in the Case record

Comment: `u1` is never inserted, so there is zero possibility that that assertion could be meaningful. Beyond that, please [edit] to specify where the exception is occurring.

Comment: @DavidReed ,thanks for your response. Please check edited code with Exception.

Comment: I've downvoted because this is the third time you have asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues with this test class.

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
```

Never use `seeAllData=true`; your test should create all required data.

```
public class CaseOwnerManagerUpdateTest {
    static testMethod void testCaseOwnerManager() {
```

The `testMethod` annotation is deprecated; use `@isTest`.

```
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
        User u1 = new User(Alias = 'standt1', Email='standarduser1@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser43431212@testorg.com');      
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@43431313testorg.com', ManagerId = u1.id);
        System.runAs(u){
```

`u1` is never inserted, so it has a `null` `Id`. `System.runAs()` will implicitly insert `u`.

```
        Case cs = new Case();
        //cs.Owner.Type = 'User';
        cs.Status = 'Working';
        cs.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Support';
```

You can't assign relationship fields that way. `RecordType` is `null`. You need to use [`getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName) to obtain the record type Id and assign it to `cs.RecordTypeId`. The same paradigm applies to the commented Owner assignment; you must assign to the `OwnerId` relationship field.

```
        // snipped

        Case case1 = [SELECT Id, Case_Owner_Manager__c, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Status != 'Closed' AND Owner.Type = 'User'  AND RecordType.DeveloperName IN ('Suppport','Support_New')];
```

You spelled a record type wrong, but this query result is never referenced, so you can simply delete it.

```
            test.startTest();
            CaseOwnerManagerUpdate obj = new CaseOwnerManagerUpdate ();
            DataBase.executeBatch(obj); 
            Case c = new Case();
            if(c.Case_Owner_Manager__c != u.ManagerId )
            c.Case_Owner_Manager__c = u.ManagerId;
           

            System.assertEquals(u1.id, c.Case_Owner_Manager__c);
            System.assertNotEquals(u.id, c.Case_Owner_Manager__c);
```

You're making assertions about a Case that exists only in memory and has not been affected by your class under test. The assertions presumably pass because the value of `c.Case_Owner_Manager__c` is `null`.

You need to query the database for test data that you inserted and validate that your batch class made the correct changes to it.